# Typescript dynamic module loading at runtime

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, dynamic-loading

I have defined an abstract `BaseClass` in a NodeJS Typescript project and I have a list of derived classes that implement and extend this `BaseClass`.

```
// baseModule.ts
export abstract class BaseClass {
  constructor() {}
  abstract method(): void;
}

export interface ModuleConstructor<T extends BaseClass> {
  new (): T
}

export function createModule<T extends BaseClass>(type: ModuleConstructor<T>): T {
  return new type();
}
```

I am trying to find a way to programmatically at runtime create an instance of one of these classes.

The constraint here is that I would like to be able to drop a new `myDerivedClass.ts` file into my project folder and have it be automatically included in a list of available modules at runtime.

The developer workflow would be 1) create new file `myNewModule.ts` 2) create and export a class that extends `BaseClass` 3) save `myNewModule.ts` to `./myModules`

```
// ./myModules/myNewModule.ts
export class MyModule extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  method() {
    //Do something custom
  }
}
```

The runtime flow (ideally without having to rebuild) would be 1) User selects from a list of available modules 2) `createModule` Factory function creates a new instance of chosen module and passes as an instance of

```
// someOtherClass.ts

const modules = require('./myModules/*') //<- Something to this effect
import { BaseClass, createModule, ModuleConstructor } from './BaseClass'

export class SomeOtherClass {
  public mod: BaseClass
  constructor(mod: ModuleConstructor) {
    this.mod = createModule(mod)
  }
}

for (let m in modules) {
  console.log(modules[m].name);
}

let someObj = SomeOtherClass(modules[m]);
someObj.mod // <- instance of derived class.
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution that I ended up using, perhaps there is an easier way though.

1) Create a dynamic module loader function
2) Use NodeJS `fs` module to scan the directory containing the modules
3) Iterate through each file and dynamic import the file into an array

```
// BaseModule.ts
import * as path from 'path'
import { promisify } from 'utils'

const readdirAsync = promisify(fs.readdir);

export async function loadModules() {
  let files = await readdirAsync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'rel/path/to/modules'));
  let imports = await Promise.all(files.map(file => (
    import(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './exchanges/brokers', file))))
  )

  // this next part will depend on how you're exporting within
  // the module. In my case, each module has an "export class"
  // statement. Typically you would "import { className } from 'moduleName'"

  let moduleNames: { [name: string]: number } = {};
  let modules: ModuleConstructor<BaseClass>[] = [];
  for (let i in imports) {
    Object.keys(imports[i]).forEach((key: string) => {
      moduleNames[key] = modules.length;
      modules.push(imports[i][key])
    })
  }
  return [moduleNames, modules];
}


// someOtherClass.ts
import { BaseClass, loadModules, ModuleConstructor } from './BaseClass'

export class SomeOtherClass<T extends BaseClass> {
  public mod: T
  constructor(mod: T ) {
    this.mod = mod;
  }
}

loadModules()
  .then(([moduleNames, modules]: [string[], ModuleConstructor<BaseClass>[]] => {

    // not necessary, but just for purpose of demonstration
    let names: string[] = Object.keys(moduleNames);
    let name = names[0]; // pick one of the module names

    // use the name dictionary as a lookup into the constructor array
    let someObj = SomeOtherClass(new modules[moduleNames[name]]);
    someObj.mod // <- instance of derived class.
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

After doing this I realized that NPM package systemJS handles dynamic loader.