# How to load modules from dynamic typescript files

Tags: node.js, typescript, configuration, node-modules

Many popular node packages support writing configuration files in JS or TS, like `webpack`, `vite`. Now I'm also trying to create a package supporting JS and TS configuration file, which would be used as: `my-package --config path/to/config.ts`.
I first tried using `require` directly, which failed for TS (that's quite an obvious result, since no loader for TS is specified).
So I then tried using `typescript` package to transpile the config file and using `require-from-string` to load the module, which doesn't work either when the specified config file import some other modules.
So my current problem is: **how to get the configuration module resolved under current context**.
Note that this package is designed to work like `webpack-cli`, being added to `devDependencies` by other packages and used as a tool for development. So the *current context* refers to the package that installs this package.
Here are some relative posts I've looked through and tried (so don't propose a duplicate to these questions):

- [How to read the .ts configuration file from the root of the project in the npm package (ESM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71291761)
- [Typescript dynamic module loading at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533921/typescript-dynamic-module-loading-at-runtime)

Comment: What's your bin script? is there like `node something.js`?

Comment: @Dimava Yeah, bin script is defined in `package.json` as `{ "bin": { "some-command": "dist/some-command.js" } }`

Comment: then try installing `tsx` and setting command to `tsc dist/some-command.js`

Comment: or even `tsx dist/some-command.ts`

Comment: @Dimava I guess you didn't quite get my purpose. I need to support all configuration formats, including json, js and ts, not merely ts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After probing into the source of `webpack-cli`, I finally get this done with the help of [`rechoir`](https://github.com/gulpjs/rechoir). Here's the code:

```
import interpret from "interpret";
import rechoir from "rechoir";
import AsyncFs from "fs/promises";
import Path from "path";
import { pathToFileURL } from "URL";

// My package is build with `webpack`, so I need the following to bypass its dynamic require constraint.
declare var __non_webpack_require__: ((id: string) => any) | undefined;
const dynamicRequire = typeof __non_webpack_require__ === "function" ? __non_webpack_require__ : require;

async function tryRequireThenImport(module: string): Promise<any> {
    let result;
    try {
        result = dynamicRequire(module);
    } catch (error: any) {
        let importEsm: ((module: string) => Promise<{ default: any }>) | undefined;
        try {
            importEsm = new Function("id", "return import(id);") as any;
        } catch (e) {
            importEsm = undefined;
        }
        if (error.code === "ERR_REQUIRE_ESM" && importEsm) {
            const urlForConfig = pathToFileURL(module).href;
            result = (await importEsm(urlForConfig)).default;
            return result;
        }
        throw error;
    }
    // For babel/typescript
    if (result && typeof result === "object" && "default" in result)
        result = result.default || {};
    return result || {};
}

async function loadModule(path: string): Promise<any> {
    const ext = Path.extname(path);
    if (ext === ".json") {
        const content = await AsyncFs.readFile(path, "utf-8");
        return JSON.parse(content);
    }
    if (!Object.keys(interpret.jsVariants).includes(ext))
        throw new Error(`Unsupported file type: ${ext}`);
    // This is the key point that gets the configuration module loaded under current context
    rechoir.prepare(interpret.jsVariants, path);
    return await tryRequireThenImport(path);
}
```

The implementation is mainly borrowed from `webpack-cli`. Here are the sources:

- [tryRequireThenImport](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/e480934116ec190d915e83fef8e2d945717963cb/packages/webpack-cli/src/webpack-cli.ts#L327)
- [loadConfigByPath](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/e480934116ec190d915e83fef8e2d945717963cb/packages/webpack-cli/src/webpack-cli.ts#L1717)